# Cross and dot product of vector fields

Tags: vector-spaces

How can I proof this statement?
As $a$ and $b$ are vector fields,
$$∇ \times (a \times b)=a(\nabla\cdot b)+(b\cdot \nabla)a-b(\nabla\cdot a)-(a\cdot ∇)b$$

And
$$ (a \cdot \nabla) a = \nabla ((a^2)/2) - a \times ( \nabla \times a)$$

Comment: What about writing down *explicitly* all those expressions...?

Comment: As DonAntonio says, just give some general expressions for the two vector fields and then take their cross products, for example $\vec{a} = (a_1,a_2,a_3)$. When you've take in try rearraging the terms so that you get the right hand side. To succeed, expand the right hand side as well and try matching the two

Comment: you have written on the right hand side the formula for the **curl** of the cross product, not the gradient. Please edit your question

Comment: use suffices, maybe?